# Writing an iterator for my own array list class in Java

Tags: java, iterator

I am writing an iterator method for my own array list class, however, when I try to test the class it says foreach loop is not applicable to MyArrayList. can anyone help me out with where I have gone wrong?

The class itself uses arrays of objects and the necessary methods to act like an arraylist (add, remove, get etc.)

Here is the class constructor and my iterator class:

```
public class MyArrayList {
public Object[] arrayList = new Object[5];
int length1 = 5;

public MyArrayList() {
}

public MyArrayList(Object[] arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    length1 = arrayList.length;
}

public ArrayListIterator iterator(){
    return new ArrayListIterator(this);
}

class ArrayListIterator<MyArrayList> implements Iterator<Object> {
    private Object[] arrayListIterable;
    private int count = 0;

    public ArrayListIterator(Object[] x){
        arrayListIterable = x;
    }

    public ArrayListIterator(MyArrayList myArrayList) {

    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        if(count < arrayList.length){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public Object next(){
        int x = count;
        count++;
        return arrayListIterable[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why it's good practice to always use the @Override tag when you think you're overriding or implementing a method - then the compiler will tell you if you're wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your `MyArrayList` class must implement [`Iterable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface.

Check the javadoc for `Iterable`:

> Implementing this interface **allows an object to be the target of the "for-each loop" statement**.

Comment: I have to include the import statement: "import java.util.Iterator;" I have alos added the @Overide tage as BarrySW19 suggested. However, with this import statement I'm unsure if I am using my own iterator or using the one provided by Java? i have read the Oracle docs on iterators and Iterable but I'm still a little confused. Thanks in advance